# Pandas: Combine two dataframes and expand rows dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got the following dataframes setup

A

`[ClaimantId], [ClaimId], [LenderId], [IsWorked]
1              1          1           1
1              2          4           0
1              3          3           1
2              6          1           1`

B

```
[ClaimantId], [Forename], [Surname]
1             Bruce       Wayne
2             Peter       Parker
```

My Desired output would be

```
[ClaimantId], [Forename], [Surname], [C1], [C2], [C3], [L1], [L2], [L3], [W1], [W2], [W3]
1             Bruce       Wayne      1      2     3    1     4     3      1    0     1
2             Peter       Parker     6      Nan   Nan  1     Nan   Nan    1    Nan   Nan
```

I'm not sure what i can apply to this, the number of C/L/W columns has an upper limit of 20 and won't ever be exceeded.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
d = {'ClaimId':'C', 'LenderId':'L','IsWorked':'W'}
df = (A.rename(columns=d)
       .set_index(['ClaimantId',A.groupby('ClaimantId').cumcount()])
       .unstack())
df.columns = [f'{i}{j+1}' for i, j in df.columns]
print (df)
               C1   C2   C3   L1   L2   L3   W1   W2   W3
ClaimantId                                             
1             1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  4.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
2             6.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN

df1 = B.join(df, on='ClaimantId')
print (df1)
    ClaimantId    Forename   Surname   C1   C2   C3   L1   L2   L3   W1   W2  \
0             1      Bruce     Wayne  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  4.0  3.0  1.0  0.0   
1             2      Peter    Parker  6.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN   

    W3  
0  1.0  
1  NaN
```

**Explanation**:

1. First `rename` columns by dict
2. Then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by counter `Series` created by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)
3. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
4. Flatten MultiIndex columns by `list comprehension` with `f-string`s
5. Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) second `DataFrame`

EDIT:

If need same length all columns use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by new `MultiIndex` created by `range`:

```
d = {'ClaimId':'C', 'LenderId':'L','IsWorked':'W'}
df = (A.rename(columns=d)
       .set_index(['ClaimantId',A.groupby('ClaimantId').cumcount()])
       .unstack())

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique(), range(5)])
df = df.reindex(columns=mux, fill_value=0)
df.columns = [f'{i}{j+1}' for i, j in df.columns]
print (df)
             C1   C2   C3  C4  C5   L1   L2   L3  L4  L5   W1   W2   W3  W4  \
ClaimantId                                                                    
1           1.0  2.0  3.0   0   0  1.0  4.0  3.0   0   0  1.0  0.0  1.0   0   
2           6.0  NaN  NaN   0   0  1.0  NaN  NaN   0   0  1.0  NaN  NaN   0   

            W5  
ClaimantId      
1            0  
2            0
```

Comment: thanks for this, looks great, trying to test at the moment and getting a keyerror on ['ClaimantId']  it appears to be happening on the ,A.groupby('[ClaimantId]').cumcount()]) part.

Comment: @CheyRav90 - What is `print (A.columns)` and `print (B.columns)` ?

Comment: A = Index(['ClaimantId', 'ClaimId', 'Lender', 'Secondary'], dtype='object')

Comment: @CheyRav90 - Thank you, then remove `[]` from columns names, answer was edited.

Comment: haha thanks, i just spent about 2 minutes trying to format my comment, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: Sorry @jezrael, just one more question, at the moment in my data the max C that there is is C18, is there an easy way so that this is always C20 and C19 and C20 are nan if nothing is there. Sorry i wasn't totally clear in the original question.

Comment: @CheyRav90 - Not sure if understand, mainly I cannot see your data with `C18`, `C19` and `C20`. Is possible explain it with data sample?

Comment: Sorry mate, basically my A dataframe can only ever have 20 or less rows per claimant id, but i want to set that instead of cumcount counting the columns that it creates a static range of 1-20. i tried using apply(lambda x: pd.Series(arange(1,20)) but it complained about non bool values. Again sorry for not being more clear in the original question.

Comment: @CheyRav90 - I understand, give me some time.

Comment: @CheyRav90 - I hope I understand it well, please check edited answer.

Comment: Perfect! I had to change range(5) to range(20) and remove the fillvalue as it was filling with 0's but that's exactly what i needed, thank you again so much, if i could upvote more i would!